# Output data from object array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to output list of user from object. This object is array and when I don't use specific number of user I get invalid data. But when I put number for user in object I get information that I need. My question is, why my code does't work properly and how to output all user?

```js
// Give Users needed types
type typeUsers = { name: string; age?: number };
// List of users
const Users: typeUsers[] = [
    {
        name: "John",
        age: 21,
    },
    {
        name: "Max",
    },
];

function UserFunc(Users) {
  // If user has age output this
    if ("age" in Users) {
        console.log(`Name: ${Users.name}, Age: ${Users.age}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`Name: ${Users.name}`);
    }
}
UserFunc(Users);
```

But also its work when I change last string to `UserFunc(Users[number])`

Comment: You seem to have gotten mixed up between operating on the array, vs. operating on the items of the array.  Your warning bells should have gone off when you wrote `Users.name` as opposed to `user.name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's common in javascript to write the variable names in `camelCase`.

Second, `Users` is an `array` of `object`, so you need to iterate over, to log each `object` inside.

```
// Give Users needed types
type typeUsers = { name: string; age?: number };
// List of users
const users: typeUsers[] = [
    {
        name: "John",
        age: 21,
    },
    {
        name: "Max",
    },
];

function userFunc(users: typeUsers[]) {
    // loop throw users array with `forEach` method
    users.forEach(user => {
      // If user has age output this  
      if ("age" in user) {
        console.log(`Name: ${user.name}, Age: ${user.age}`);
      } else {
        console.log(`Name: ${user.name}`);
      }
    })
}
userFunc(users);
```

[This is a working exmaple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHEEsDcFNQKoGdYCcmgHa1gEz6AC4CeADrEgLABQJ5RZsyaGAvKAN5YCGAtrAC5QSQqkiYA5gG5Q3CbAD8QzAFdeAIzSgAvlJohQAGUgjQAewBmoFSnQ0AxmcymbLIXSa2kAbQC6odm8aUBDOYNCIzD5BUAAiACkzAAtMWIAacIiQuRiAJgBGDOoI7SKIjkysqP4hWIBZbgAPdMrSml89ahoLFUx7Qkgna1sAMV77AApXdHdGZnQ-AEow4tDppAA6CzNUAFFueySp2wCAPhWs0AMASStp0CTuDBzzFUJSN6IkkxDKkMgrBNYjlYqBxMM0MsKqtLo5nGYADawDYIswSCYAAwActEhAASDjTDbVWClUAAQXk+MJtg2OW0GMWnUu2lAsARKAul1AcKQiORqPR2NxoAJRJJDKZfx0rUWNG0NGmYz6xxYTKAA)

Answer (score 0):

`if ("age" in Users)` only works with objects, not with arrays. you can loop over the array like that:

```
// Give Users needed types
type typeUsers = { name: string; age?: number };
// List of users
const Users: typeUsers[] = [
    {
        name: "John",
        age: 21,
    },
    {
        name: "Max",
    },
];

function UserFunc(Users: any) {
  // If user has age output this
        Users.forEach((User: any)=>{
        if ("age" in User) {
            console.log(`Name: ${User.name}, Age: ${User.age}`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Name: ${User.name}`);
        }
    })
}
UserFunc(Users);
```

Answer (score 0):

Users is an array. So in order to access an element in array you have to do Users[0].name or Users[1].name.

Or, if you want to output all the data, wrap your if else structure in an Array.forEach() like so:

```
// Give Users needed types
type typeUsers = { name: string; age?: number };
// List of users
const Users: typeUsers[] = [
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: "Max"
  }
];

function UserFunc(Users: typeUsers[]) {
  // If user has age output this

  Users.forEach((user) => {
    if ("age" in user) {
      console.log(`Name: ${user.name}, Age: ${user.age}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Name: ${user.name}`);
    }
  });
}
UserFunc(Users);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are checking for the User property `age` directly from the array. As others have pointed out, you need to loop through the array to access each of the User object where the check for property `age` will be valid.

```js
  // Give Users needed types
  type typeUsers = { name: string; age?: number };
// List of users
const Users: typeUsers[] = [
  {
      name: "John",
      age: 21,
  },
  {
      name: "Max",
  },
];

function UserFunc(Users) {
// If user has age output this
  for (const user of Users) {
     if ("age" in user) {
       console.log(`Name: ${user.name}, Age: ${user.age}`);
     } else {
       console.log(`Name: ${user.name}`);
     }
  }
}
UserFunc(Users);
```